# Prevent updates to navigation properties in EF-core

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Please how can we prevent EF.core from trying to insert/update foreign-key tables when we create a new primary entity?

This Exception is thrown:

```
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'clients' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'guards' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'penalties' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

My code is as follows:

```
  public class Offence
  {
    [Key]
    public Int32 offence_id { get; set; }

    public Int32? guard_id { get; set; }
    public Int32? penalty_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dt_recorded { get; set; }
    public Int32? salary_id { get; set; }
    public Decimal? amount { get; set; }
    public String status { get; set; }
    public Int32? site_id { get; set; }

    public Guard Guard { get; set; }
    public Salary Salary { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    public Penalty Penalty { get; set; }
  }
```

Any attempt to create a new `Offence` gives errors, as EF.core tries to run inserts for the related navigation properties:

```
public Guard Guard { get; set; }
public Salary Salary { get; set; }
public Site Site { get; set; }
public Penalty Penalty { get; set; }
```

How can we prevent this?

Edit: Create and update code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Offence o)
{
  if (o == null)
  {
    return BadRequest();
  }

  o.last_modified_by = int.Parse(((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);
  o.last_modified = DateTime.Now;

  await db.AddAsync(o);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();

  return CreatedAtRoute("GetOffenceAsync", new { id = o.offence_id }, o);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your update code?

Comment: @H.Herzl i've added the Create & Update code, and the Error I have been getting

Comment: I need to see what type is db, I guess is a DbSet

Comment: `db` is a `DbContext`

```
    private readonly RSGContext db;

    public OffencesController(RSGContext context)
    {
      db = context;
    }
```

Comment: Why you don't set identity for your entities? e.g. [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Comment: ah, i see i thought i only needed `[key]`

Comment: @H.Herzl i've added that, makes no difference

Comment: OK, it seems like your navigation properties have values, please check your navigation property have null value before to save, by the way, why you don't use db.Set<Offence>() instead of db.Add?

Comment: @H.Herzl Thanks! that solves it. I need to set the navigation properties to null before calling Add or save. Please post this as the answer, i'll accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your navigation properties have values, please check your navigation property have null reference before to save; EF Core save logic try to save navigation properties if they have value.

Let me know if this is useful

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work, I had to `null-out` the navigation properties before saving.

However if sending the initial object back with `CreatedAtRoute`, then you need to cache the `nulled-out` properties and add them back to before you return:

Actual code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Offence o)
{
  if (o == null)
  {
    return BadRequest();
  }

  o.last_modified_by = int.Parse(((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);
  o.last_modified = DateTime.Now;

  var _g = o.Guard;
  var _p = o.Penalty;
  var _s = o.Site;

  o.Guard = null;
  o.Penalty = null;
  o.Site = null;

  await db.AddAsync(o);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();

  o.Guard = _g;
  o.Penalty = _p;
  o.Site = _s;

  return CreatedAtRoute("GetOffenceAsync", new { id = o.offence_id }, o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set those properties as `virtual`. This way EF knows what's part of the model and what is an navigational property. Also this will enable the LazyLoading mechanism you need.

```
public virtual Guard Guard { get; set; }
public virtual Salary Salary { get; set; }
public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
public virtual Penalty Penalty { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I still get same set of errors, regardless of virtual or not

Comment: SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'clients' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'guards' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'penalties' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: The exception occurs in each table so post please your classes for each one and also the configuration. If these classes have a property called `Id` EF will know that is the primary key and configure accordingly. However if you use other name for the pk you must set it manually.

Comment: all my classes have pk named `classname_id`, so i uses `[key]` on each